How to hide or disable the extra handle of React-three TransformControls when using scale mode
enter image description here
I just want the red green and blue part and want to hide or disable other scale properties.I look for the option to hide or disable it but i didn't found on the library and i also checked their official website but didn't found anything helpful on how to hide or disable the extra options

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
